# Fixture generator code

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
$totalRounds = 1;
$teams = array('Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4', 'Team 5');
echo 'Total Teams: ' , $totalTeams = count($teams) , '<br/>';
$turns = $totalTeams;

for($round=1; $round<$totalRounds+1; $round++){
    echo 'Round: ' , $round , '<br/>';

    for($homeTeam=0; $homeTeam<$totalTeams-1; $homeTeam++){
        for($awayTeam=0; $awayTeam<$totalTeams; $awayTeam++){
            if($teams[$homeTeam] != $teams[$awayTeam]){
                echo $teams[$homeTeam] , ' v/s ' , $teams[$awayTeam] , '<br/>';
            }                        
        }
        unset($teams[$homeTeam]);
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

My expected output is:

```
Team 1 v/s Team 2 <br/>
Team 1 v/s Team 3 <br/>
Team 1 v/s Team 4 <br/>
Team 1 v/s Team 5 <br/>
Team 2 v/s Team 3 <br/>
Team 2 v/s Team 4 <br/>
Team 2 v/s Team 5 <br/>
Team 3 v/s Team 4 <br/>
Team 3 v/s Team 5 <br/>
Team 4 v/s Team 5 <br/>
```

My actual output is giving me undefined index errors

Once this is fixed I don't know how to assign home and away teams. Eg. Team 1 should have only 2 home games, instead it has 4. Each team will play 2 home games and 2 away games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is destroying the array as it goes, e.g:

```
first iteration: $home = 0; $away = 0
end of iteration: delete teams[0]

second iteration, $home = 1; $away = 0 - OOPS, teams[0] no longer exists
```

instead of unsetting the array as you go, you should be basing the inner loop on the outer loop, e.g:

```
for($home = 0; ...) {
   for($away = $home + 1; ...) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your code with the following

```
$totalRounds = 1;
$teams = array('Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4', 'Team 5');
echo 'Total Teams: ' , $totalTeams = count($teams) , '<br/>';
$turns = $totalTeams;

for($round=1; $round<$totalRounds+1; $round++){
    echo 'Round: ' , $round , '<br/>';

    for($homeTeam = 0; $homeTeam < $totalTeams - 1; $homeTeam++) {
        for($awayTeam=$homeTeam + 1; $awayTeam < $totalTeams; $awayTeam++) {
            echo $teams[$homeTeam] , ' v/s ' , $teams[$awayTeam] , '<br/>';
        }
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Marc & Philipp. How do I get two home games and two away games for each team?