# Football Fixture Generation

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, generator

I am designing a football tournament generator and have found this great script for generating fixtures from another user on this site ([Fixture generator code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927480/fixture-generator-code?rq=1)).
The script takes the teams and arranges one match against the others which works perfectly.
My question is:  How do I sort the resulting matches so that the teams don't play each other straight away after their match finishes.  I would ideally like each team to have at least a "one match break" before their next game.

Here is the script so far:

```
$totalRounds = 1;
$teams= array("Team 1","Team 2","Team 3","Team 4","Team 5");
echo 'Total Teams: ' , $totalTeams = count($teams) , '<br/>';
$turns = $totalTeams;
for($round=1; $round<$totalRounds+1; $round++){
        for($homeTeam = 0; $homeTeam < $totalTeams - 1; $homeTeam++) {
            for($awayTeam=$homeTeam + 1; $awayTeam < $totalTeams; $awayTeam++) {
                $home= $teams[$homeTeam];
                $away= $teams[$awayTeam];
                echo "$home vs $away<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

This displays the following:

Team 1 vs Team 2
Team 1 vs Team 3
Team 1 vs Team 4
Team 1 vs Team 5
Team 2 vs Team 3
Team 2 vs Team 4
Team 2 vs Team 5
Team 3 vs Team 4
Team 3 vs Team 5
Team 4 vs Team 5

What I would ideally like is something along the lines of:

Team 3 vs Team 5
Team 1 vs Team 2
Team 3 vs Team 4
Team 2 vs Team 5
Team 1 vs Team 4
Team 2 vs Team 3
Team 1 vs Team 5
Team 2 vs Team 4
Team 1 vs Team 3
Team 4 vs Team 5

Comment: can you explain a little more what you except, a better dispatch ? a random association ? or exactly what you post ?

Comment: I'm not looking for an exact match to what I posted.  I just need it so that both teams in each match do not play again straight away.  It's for under 16's football and don't really want to knacker the boys out by playing two, or more, games in a row :)

Comment: maybe this page can help you, 
http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10300945-Round-Robin-Generator&s=e5e292d8195c1a7019c35bc610b8cd6a&p=11003487&viewfull=1#post11003487

Comment: Thanks for the link (i have seen a few pages offering the same information) but it generates a round robin fixture list which is not what i'm looking for and cannot be tweaked to what I need.  I am just looking for a way to generate the fixtures for one "group" of matches.

Comment: Store the original order into array-1.  Then start a second while loop to keep trying to find a good order until it succeeds.  Inside the while loop have a for loop to create a shuffled copy of array-1 as array-2.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'll work on that and feedback if I can get it to work.